# Alternative to display-toggle when I am not certain that the element uses display:block when visible?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working in a project where theer are many js procedures like the following:

```
if (show)
    $('.some-element').css('display', 'block');
else
    $('.some-element').css('display', 'none');
```

How can I achieve the same thing when I don't want to require that `.some-element` uses `display: block;` when visible?

`.some-element` might for example have been designed to use `display: inline-block;` or `display: flex;`.

Limitations:

- I don't want the element to take up any space when hidden. For this reason I think that the popular methods `visibility: none;` and `opacity: 0;` would not work.
- I don't want to save any state in js, for example to remember the original display property value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this

```
if (show)
    $('.some-element').css('display', '');
else
    $('.some-element').css('display', 'none');
```

This code (`$('.some-element').css('display', '');`) will remove the inline  `display: none` property , when it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's already solved this problem for you with [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), and [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$('.some-element').toggle(show);
```

or

```
if (show) {
    $('.some-element').show();
} else {
    $('.some-element').hide();
}
```

Comment: This is true, but jQuery internally has to work kind-of hard to figure out what `.show()` should do.

Comment: @Pointy - True. I'm guessing there's a good reason for that, based on 12 years or so of hardening. :-) Unlikely to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Oh agreed, yes.

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do is use a class for the hidden state, because you *do* know that when the element is hidden the `display` property should be `none`.

```
.whatever {
  // normal rules
}

.whatever.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Then you manipulate the visibility of the element by adding or removing the "hidden" class. Since your rules don't affect the visible rules for the element, it can be `display: inline;` or `display: table-cell;` or anything else.

This approach can get complicated when there are in-line "style" attributes; that's a reason I don't generally like those in my code.

Another alternative to using `display` is to give the element an absolute position far off the visible page:

```
.whatever.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
}
```

This is useful for form fields that need to be invisible but which also need to actually work as form fields. Internet Explorer in particular does not like invisible (`display: none`) inputs, but it's OK with ones positioned off the screen.